# re-connecting to a python socket client, after it has rebooted

Tags: python, sockets, reboot, reconnect

So I am doing a project at work, where I am communicating with an external IO-Module PCB, over a TCP connection. So essentially a GUI, talking to an embedded system, via TCP.
I then want to add a command, where I can ask the PCB do reboot, and automatically reconnect with the PCB when this is done.
I have snipped out the sections of the code that is relevant to my question (it is supposed to be way bigger, but this section should illustrate the problem) - please dont look to much into the "reboot signal" function, this only makes sense to you if you have the full understanding of the external PCB and how that works (think of it as a signal, that reboots the PCB, nothing else)

My thought is that i need some kind of "socket.forget" function, I am not sure I am correct in this assumption. As you can see in the code, I am calling a "socket.close" function, and want to then re-use the same function as i connected with in the first place. But that gives me an "AttributeError: 'socket' object has no attribute 'socket'" error.

```
import socket
import time

global socket

def connect():
   global socket
   connected = 0

   socket = socket.socket()

   try:
      socket.bind(("192.168.0.10", 2333))

   except:
      print("connection failed")

   else:
      print("connecting")

      for x in range(0, 2):
         if connected == 0:
            adress = '192.168.0.240'
            server_address = (adress, 2333)
            print('starting up on {} port {}'.format(*server_address))
            try:
               socket.connect(server_address)

            except:
               print("trying again")

            else:
               print("connection successfully established")
               connected = 1

   if connected == 0:
      print("connection failed")

def reboot_signal():
   filler_byte = 0

   reboot = 1
   checksum = 1


   socket.send(bytes([filler_byte, checksum, filler_byte, reboot, filler_byte,filler_byte ,filler_byte,filler_byte, filler_byte,filler_byte, filler_byte,filler_byte, filler_byte,filler_byte, filler_byte,filler_byte, filler_byte,filler_byte, filler_byte,filler_byte, filler_byte,filler_byte, filler_byte,filler_byte, filler_byte,filler_byte, filler_byte,filler_byte, filler_byte,filler_byte, filler_byte,filler_byte, filler_byte,filler_byte, filler_byte,filler_byte, filler_byte,filler_byte, filler_byte,filler_byte, filler_byte,filler_byte, filler_byte,filler_byte, filler_byte,filler_byte, filler_byte,filler_byte, filler_byte,filler_byte, filler_byte,filler_byte, filler_byte,filler_byte, filler_byte,filler_byte, filler_byte,filler_byte, filler_byte,filler_byte, filler_byte,filler_byte, filler_byte,filler_byte, filler_byte,filler_byte, filler_byte,filler_byte, filler_byte,filler_byte, filler_byte,filler_byte, filler_byte,filler_byte, filler_byte,filler_byte, filler_byte,filler_byte, filler_byte,filler_byte, filler_byte,filler_byte, filler_byte,filler_byte, filler_byte,filler_byte, filler_byte,filler_byte, filler_byte,filler_byte, filler_byte,filler_byte, filler_byte,filler_byte, filler_byte,filler_byte, filler_byte,filler_byte, filler_byte,filler_byte, filler_byte,filler_byte, filler_byte,filler_byte, filler_byte,filler_byte, filler_byte,filler_byte, filler_byte,filler_byte, filler_byte,filler_byte, filler_byte,filler_byte, filler_byte,filler_byte, filler_byte,filler_byte, filler_byte,filler_byte, filler_byte,filler_byte, filler_byte,filler_byte, filler_byte,filler_byte, filler_byte,filler_byte, filler_byte,filler_byte, filler_byte,filler_byte, filler_byte,filler_byte]))

def reboot_PCB():
   global socket

   reboot_signal()   # dont worry about this, this is essentially just a TCP signal, rebooting the PCB I am communicating with
   print('rebooting')
   socket.close()
   time.sleep(10) # Now I am giving the PCB some time to reboot

   connect() # now i want to re-connect

connect()

time.sleep(5) # Now I am giving the PCB some time to reboot

a = 1

#my alternative way of making and endless loop
while( a == 1):
   reboot_PCB()
```

Comment: *"socket = socket.socket()"* - don't call you internal variable the same as the package, so that you don't run into the "AttributeError: 'socket' object has no attribute 'socket'" problem

Comment: I know if isn't the point of your question but.... the reboot value sent could be composed in a far more readable way using the [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) library. `send_value = struct.pack('xBxB130x', checksum, reboot)` should give you the same value.